# What is the output of this code in Java?

Tags: java, class

I've tried to run the code and I receive the error "point cannot be resolved to a variable". Why am I getting this error and please try running the code yourself and share what the output you're getting is. Thanks.

```
public class ReferenceMystery1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 7;
        int b = 9;
        Point p1 = new Point(2,2);
        Point p2 = new Point(2,2);
        addToXTwice(a, p1);
        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + p1.x + " " + p2.x);
        addToXTwice(b, p2);
        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + p1.x + " " + p2.x);

    }

    public static void addToXTwice(int a, Point b) {
        a = a + a;
        p1.x = a;
        System.out.println(a + " " + p1.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `b.x` instead of `p1.x` because there is no `p1` in this function scope  `addToXTwice(int a, Point b)`

Comment: We will also get same error, where have you imported `Point`?

Comment: Share the whole stack trace. Also share the whole detail of Point Class. Is it a class written by you ? or is it java.awt.Point or is it org.openqa.selenium.Point?

Answer (score 2):

import point class

```
import java.awt.Point;
```

replace

```
p1.x = a;
System.out.println(a + " " + p1.x);
```

to

```
b.x = a;
System.out.println(a + " " + b.x);
```

complete working code is

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 9;
    Point p1 = new Point(2,2);
    Point p2 = new Point(2,2);
    addToXTwice(a, p1);
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + p1.x + " " + p2.x);
    addToXTwice(b, p2);
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + p1.x + " " + p2.x);
}

public static void addToXTwice(int a, Point b) {
    a = a + a;
    b.x = a;
    System.out.println(a + " " + b.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is also one of the problem, but it won't completely solve OP's issue as OP hasn't imported required classes.

Answer (score 0):

"Point" class is not available for me to run your program.

Assuming its available and you are able to compile, then, as previous responses indicated...you can't access p1.x within addToXTwice() method, as the input params are 'a' and 'b'.

with "import java.awt.Point", I get the following compilation errors

> javac -g ReferenceMystery1.java
>   ReferenceMystery1.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
>       p1.x = a;
>       ^
>     symbol:   variable p1
>     location: class ReferenceMystery1
>   ReferenceMystery1.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
>       System.out.println(a + " " + p1.x);
>                                    ^
>     symbol:   variable p1
>     location: class ReferenceMystery1
>   2 errors

These are in alignment with previous comments of "p1" not available from within addToXTwice() method.

Comment: `addToXTwice(int a, Point b)` instead of p1 there is b passed as argument so you should have to change p1 inside in addToXTwice() method